# How to implement a short pause in Vaadin

Tags: java, time, vaadin, wait, sleep

I'm trying to make a sorting algorithm visualizer, which visually displays the integers as bars and shows changes made to the array at each step. I am using Vaadin 23.1.0 and Java 17. All the sorting algorithms and other UI work properly so far, but I haven't been able to get it to pause briefly between steps. I've tried using Thread.sleep and TimeUnit.SECONDS.Sleep, but in both cases, it doesn't pause between steps. It just has a long loading bar at the top of the view, then shows the end sorted array.
Code:

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout{
//set up UI and display initial unsorted array
buttonBeginSort.addClickListener(e -> {
            bubbleSort();
        });
}
public void bubbleSort()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length-i-1; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                {
                    swapIndexes(j,j+1);
                }
            }
        }
}
public void swapIndexes(int a, int b) {
        //swap array elements
        //display new, modified array

        waitBetweenSteps();
}
public void waitBetweenSteps()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
}
```

With all this considered, how can I make a brief pause in a Vaadin web app?

Comment: You should consider using a ProgressBar https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/progress-bar

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin application as many other web applications are running in server and browser at the same time. User interaction and UI updates are based on HTTP requests. Hence you can't design the application based on fully synchronous processes.

If you need a pause, you need to run your process in a background thread using Executor, you need to enable also the [Push](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/advanced/server-push) functionality of Vaadin and use UI#access to periodically update the view from the background thread.